# How to create a contact of a sourcing project using SAP Cloud SDK and a generated OData v4 client?

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk, s4hana

I generated an ODATA v4 client for the [SAP S/4HANA Sourcing Project API](https://api.sap.com/api/OP_SOURCINGPROJECT_0001/resource/Sourcing_Project) like described [here](https://api.sap.com/api/OP_SOURCINGPROJECT_0001/cloud-sdk/Java).

All in all it works quite well. I can query, update or delete sourcing project data, milestones and contacts using batch requests, e.g. like this:

```
OPSOURCINGPROJECT0001Service sourcingProjectService = new DefaultOPSOURCINGPROJECT0001Service()
    .withServicePath("/sap/opu/odata4/sap/api_sourcingproject/srvd_a2x/sap/sourcingproject/0001");

BatchRequestBuilder batchRequestBuilder = sourcingProjectService.batch();

batchRequestBuilder.addChangeset(sourcingProjectService.deleteSourcingProjectContact(sapContact1));
batchRequestBuilder.addChangeset(sourcingProjectService
    .updateSourcingProjectContact(sapContact).includingFields(Contact.BUSINESS_PARTNER));
batchRequestBuilder.addChangeset(sourcingProjectService
    .updateSourcingProject(sourcingProject).includingFields(SourcingProject.PURCHASER_RESPONSIBLE));

BatchResponse batchResponse = batchRequestBuilder
    .withHeader("prefer", "odata.continue-on-error")
    .withQueryParameter("saml2", "disabled")
    .execute(destination);
```

However I can't figure out, how to create a new contact like it is described for the javascript version of the client, see [here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/js/features/odata/v4-client#create-as-child-of).

How can I do that in a batch request? There is no `createSourcingProjectContact`-method in the generated service-class.

I tried to use the `CreateRequestBuilder` directly cheating a bit like this:

```
private CreateRequestBuilder<Contact> createSourcingProjectContact(SourcingProject sourcingProject, Contact sapContact) {
    String servicePath = config.getSapServicePathSourcingProject();
    String resourceEntity = "SourcingProject(" + sourcingProject.getSourcingProjectUUID() + ")/_SourcingProjectContact";
    return new CreateRequestBuilder<>(servicePath, sapContact, resourceEntity);
}
```

But when I add the result to the batch using the `batchRequestBuilder` it will escape the URI of the corresponding post request and transform `(` to `%28` for example which renders that part of the batch request invalid as far as the SAP-partner-system is concerned.

It also does not work to send the create-requests outside of a batch, since still the SDK will encode the '/' in the 'resourceEntity' and such in the resulting URI.

Any help would be highly appreciated, since it is a pressing matter. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `forEntity` API and pass it on to the `BatchRequestBuilder` after the create request of sourcing project data.

```java
sourcingProjectService.forEntity( sourcingProject ) // The project to which contact should be added.
    .navigateTo( theNavigationPropety ) // Should be something like SourcingProject.TO_SOURCING_PROJECT_CONTACT
    .create( contact ); //Supply your contact object here
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no method `forEntity`in the `OPSOURCINGPROJECT0001Service` created by the generator. Are there maybe certain flags I am not aware of?

Comment: the `forEntity` method is not available on the interface `OPSOURCINGPROJECT0001Service` but is available on the implementation `DefaultOPSOURCINGPROJECT0001Service`.Please change `sourcingProjectService` variable to type `DefaultOPSOURCINGPROJECT0001Service` instead to access it.

Comment: Nope, there is no "forEntity" in the entire generated code. There are some method comments e.g. in the class `SourcingProject` that reference such a method: `To execute it use the {@code service.forEntity(entity).applyAction(thisAction)} API`. Still there is no such method in the client. Does `service` maybe reference something in the SDK itself here?

Comment: Ok, I get it, the method is defined in `ServiceWithNavigableEntities` which is implemented by the implementation but not extended in the interface. That is a questionable structure, but I should be able to try that. This way you have to use the concrete type instead of working with the interface which gets kind of useless then.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works now. Still I would expect the interface to provide all public features ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, not all services support this navigation. Furthermore, we can't simply add it to the interface in a non-breaking way. That is why, at least for now, this API is not available on the interface. But I agree, the interface is of rather limited use in this case.